# d3.js Profile completeness app

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I've created a profile completeness app - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/293/

I'd like to morph the colour based on the final level reached. Red on a low level, yellow on a medium - green/blue on a higher level.

```
                var bar = barrects.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data);

                // Enter
                bar.enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("y", methods.height);

                // Update
                bar
                    .attr("y", methods.height)
                    .attr("height", initialHeight)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .attr("x", function(d) { return methods.x(d.letter); })
                    .attr("width", methods.x.rangeBand())
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return methods.y(d.frequency); })
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return methods.height - methods.y(d.frequency); })

                // Exit
                bar.exit()
                    .transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .attr("y", initialHeight)
                    .attr("height", initialHeight)
                    .remove();
```

Comment: Congratulations for creating a profile completeness app! Did I miss the question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/297/ - well yes. Trying to add the label to the chart itself. Also if there is a way to round the chart - without the border-radius div wrapper

Comment: Got an error generating the BBox http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/300/

Comment: I've fixed the pointer code - but will need to integrate it back - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/302/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I've cleaned up the code to have this as the latest example. It contains the progress chart and labeling system. I'd like to animate the labeling system - so the pointer animates alongside the bar in the progress chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/316/

```
var progressChart = {
    init: function(){

        var data = [
            {
                "label": "All Star",
                "y": 10,
                "x": 160,
                "cx": 70,
                "value" : 90
            }
        ];

        var minLimit = 0;
        var maxLimit = 100;

        this.width = 560;
        this.height = 300;

        this.completeWidth = 130;
        this.completeHeight = 100;


        // setup scales

        this.x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, this.completeWidth], .1);

        this.y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([this.completeHeight, 0]);

        this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(this.x)
            .orient("bottom");

        this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(this.y)
            .orient("left"); 
        // setup scales

        // chart container
        var progresschart = d3.select(".progresschart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.completeWidth)
            .attr("height", this.completeHeight)
        .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,5)");

         this.chart = progresschart.append("g")
            .attr("class", "chart")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-15,0)");
        // chart container

         //_label containers
         var progresslabels = d3.select(".progresslabels").append("svg")
             .attr("width", this.width)
             .attr("height", this.height)
             .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,5)");

        this.labels = progresslabels.append("g")
            .attr("class", "labels")        

        this.pointers = progresslabels.append("g")
            .attr("class", "pointers")
        //_label containers

        this.y.domain([minLimit, maxLimit]);

        this.chartBuild(data); 
        this.addLabels(data);
    },
    chartBuild: function(data){
        var that = this;

        var selector = ".progresschart";

        var svg = d3.select(selector);

        var barrects = d3.select(selector + " .chart");        

            var bar = barrects.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data);

            // Enter
            bar.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("y", that.completeHeight);

            // Update
            bar
            .attr("y", that.completeHeight)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("width", that.x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) { return that.y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return that.completeHeight - that.y(d.value); })

            // Exit
            bar.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(250)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .remove();

    },
    addLabels: function(data){
        var that = this;

            //build cy val from value 
            data[0].cy = 100 - data[0].value;

            //__labels  

            //__ enter
            var labels = that.labels.selectAll("text")
            .data(data);

            labels.enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

            //__ update            
            labels
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return d.y;
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.label; 
            })
            .each(function(d) {
                var bbox = this.getBBox();
                d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
                d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
                d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(300)

            labels
            .transition()
            .duration(300)      

            //__ exit
            labels.exit().remove();
            //__labels            


                //__pointers
            that.pointers.append("defs").append("marker")
                    .attr("id", "circ")
                    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                    .attr("refX", 3)
                    .attr("refY", 3)
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", 3)
                    .attr("cy", 3)
                    .attr("r", 3);

                var pointers = that.pointers.selectAll("path.pointer")
                    .data(data);

                //__ enter
                pointers.enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("class", "pointer")
                    .style("fill", "none")
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)");

                //__ update
                pointers
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                        if(d.cx > d.ox) {
                            return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
                        } else {
                            return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
                        }
                    })
                    .transition()
                        .duration(300)

                pointers
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)      

                //__ exit
                pointers.exit().remove();
                //__pointers    

    }
}


progressChart.init()
```